# socket.io intellisense not working in WebStorm on Server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webstorm, intellisense

Having trouble with code completion / intellisense. The following works because I have properly installed `@types/socket.io`:

```
// in an express app
let io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on("connection", ()=>{} );
```

But in this next case `on` is unresolved in `socket.on`:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
    app.io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
}
```

If I go to the type definition I see that `Socket` extends `NodeJS.EventEmitter`, which has a properly defined `on` property. If I add an entry in the type definition file for `on` in the socket.io type definition file WebStorm is happy - in this one case of `socket.on`, but this is not a solution.

What could be the problem? 
What is a solution?

Comment: Both are accepted actually, and in my opinion its not clear that "connect" is better. Events are nouns that encapsulate some verb jump click connection etc. "connect" is active, yet "on" means that this thing just happened, so it could be proper to say that it is the "connected" event.

Answer (score 0):

The connection event is a server side only, means new socket connect on it. The connect event is client side, means the socket is connected. Check socket.io doc